# List is returning null when running the expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I have a question,...
i'm using following code:

```
Expression<Func<Administrator, bool>> function = (Administrator a) => (a.User.Username.Equals(username) && a.User.Password.Equals(password));

List<Administrator> admins = uow.AdministratorRepository.find(function).ToList();
```

the result in the admins list is a list of Administrators where the username and password of the User property of the Administrators are equal to the wanted credentials. But my big question now is why for every Administrator `admin.User` is returning `null`. I don't get it, maybe it is something small but I don't see it. So the property returns null but it is checked in the expression. Hope you can help me?

Comment: are you using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `.Include("UserRelationshipPropertyName")`, basically you'll have to tell the framework to load the user objects as well.